# A natural alternative for "become familiar with someone"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**Edited:**

As I see on the web pages, the word **familiar** is mostly used for things rather than people. For example although you can get familiar with someone, but most of the times, you use it for "something".

I.e. "how did you get/become familiar with our company" which to me sounds a bit formal.

I need to know, how a native speaker would say the bold part below in natural English:

> A: You seem to be too friendly and that's pleasant to me.
>
> B: That would be more interesting to you if you know that we **became familiar with each other** just yesterday.

Does my sentence sound idiomatic or you confirm my understanding?

**Edited scenario:**

> A: Guys. I like the respect and mutual understanding between you two. You're really good friends. I like the way you are treating each other. That appears pleasant to me.
>
> B: Thank you. I think it would be interesting to you to know that we **became familiar with each other** just yesterday. We disn't know each other by yesterday. We met at the gym and made quick friends the previous day.

Comment: How do you define "familiar"?

Comment: Everything / everyone that is easy to recognize, while you have already seen, heard, met it/them.

Comment: What you describe is closer to "acquainted". "Familiar" is closer to "friends" - but not at all synonyms.

Comment: Do you mean “unpleasant”? When someone is *too* something that’s usually considered a bad thing. Your second sentence doesn’t quite make sense to me. Does the first person not realize they met the second person the previous day?

Comment: Your sentence B sounds as if it is talking  with a second person about the speaker's relationship with a third person. Is that correct? More context would help.

Comment: Might I suggest: "Get to know"? Or were you looking for a single word?

Comment: "We got acquainted with each other just yesterday" works in this instance.

Comment: Yes @Bee; I think so. Both "we got acquainted with each other just yesterday" and "we got to know each other just yesterday" mean the same to me and work properly, while the my sentence works but in a very formal case I think.

Comment: Then @virolino please have a look on the first definition of Canbridge https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/familiar

Comment: Well @Mixolydian; let me edit my thread. You're right about the usage of "too" and its connotation. I will add the edited version of my scenario at the end of the thread.

Comment: @Bee -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Please @David Siegel consider my edited thread. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @A-friend your question is more clear - thanks for the edit.

Comment: You're welcome @Mixolydian. Sorry again. It's just because of lacking the needed sense of us non-natives. You speak by instinct and we most of the times try to translate. :)

Comment: I forgot to say @Bee that to me "we got acquainted with each other just yesterday" sounds too formal. Does it sound to you the same?

Comment: Yes I agree it sounds pretty formal, but in my opinion, so does become familiar. Might I suggest you use  "we became friends"

Comment: Or, "we got to know each other"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just say "we **met [each other]** just yesterday". B and C (let's call the other person they're talking about that) did not know each other before they encountered each other at the gym yesterday. "each other" is optional - "we met" and "we met each other" both work here. Or, as Bee suggests in a comment, "we **got to know each other** just yesterday" works too and makes it clear that B and C didn't just introduce themselves, but became well-acquainted (and in this case friendly) with one another.